# passing value onchange select Struts1

Tags: jsp, struts

I have the select below on a JSP

```
  <bean:define name="forma_rec_gruposGlosas" id="idComboArea" property="comboArea" />
    <html:select property="area" styleId="area" onblur="FondoSinFoco();" onchange="update_onChange(this.value);">
        <html:options collection="idComboArea" property="id" labelProperty="description" />
</html:select>
```

So what I want is to pass the value selected in the select to the function update_onChange on the onchange part

Comment: Get the selected value in the onchange function.

Answer (score 0):

use struts-bean tag library -

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/taglib/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>

update_onChange('<bean:write name="forma_rec_gruposGlosas" property="id"/>');
```

on your `onchange` event

```
function update_onChange(id){
 // your code here
}
```